# MVC 4 Application using Kendo UI ASP.net MVC toolkit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, telerik

I am using "kendoui.aspnetmvc.2013.2.918.commercial" version to develop MVC Application.Now i could not find Masked textbox control in intellisence.What is the cause  ?

@(Html.Kendo().MaskedTextbox . When i type this there is no such name in the intellisence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MaskedTextbox widget was not added until 2014 Q1. [Here are the release notes that mention it.](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-03-19/kendo-ui-q1-2014-release-announcement) You would need to upgrade to at least this version.